# Different Styles for same class name but different id

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this markup:

```
<div id="slider1">
    <div class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <a style="left: 0%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="slider2">
    <div class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        <a style="left: 0%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i want is different style elements for the two  elements. They are contained in outer div with different id's. Is this possible? And also this markup is auto generated by the jqueryui plugin so i can't modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write

```
#slider1 .ui-slider{
    //styles;
    !important;
}

#slider2 .ui-slider{
    //styles;
    !important;
}
```

By writing !important it'll override auto generated styles..

Answer (score 1):

To apply css to the two elements just use rules like this

```
#slider1 .ui-slider {
    //style 1
}
#slider2 .ui-slider {
    //style 2
}
```

Comment: I am positive this works. Do you mean example styles or what?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible

For the first outer div

```
#slider1 .ui-slider
```

For the second outer div

```
#slider2 .ui-slider
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes now you can define same css properties as like this

```
     #slider1  .ui-slider{
    xxxx:xxxx; // css properties 
    }

 #slider2  .ui-slider{
xxxx:xxxx; // css properties 
}
```

---

and now this second option is

```
     #slider1 > .ui-slider{
    xxxx:xxxx; // css properties 
    }

 #slider2 > .ui-slider{
xxxx:xxxx; // css properties 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Style with parent child relationship like

```
parent_id/class child_id/class
{//do stuff here
}
```

Here like

```
#slider1 div{
style for 1st one div}
#slider2 div{
style for 2nd one div}
#slider1 a{
style for 1st one a}
#slider2 a{
style for 2nd one a}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your css file, or code block   and try to minimize style="" in the markup.  Follow these specificity guides:

Specificity is calculated by counting various components of your css and expressing them in a form (a,b,c,d). This will be clearer with an example, but first the components.

Element, Pseudo Element: d = 1 – (0,0,0,1)
Class, Pseudo class, Attribute: c = 1 – (0,0,1,0)
Id: b = 1 – (0,1,0,0)
Inline Style: a = 1 – (1,0,0,0)
An id is more specific than a class is more specific than an element.

from: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

```
 <style>
    .class1 {}
    .class2 {}
    #id1 {}
    #id2 {}
 </style>
```