# Is there condition statement for same class but different ID?

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Is there a kind of condition statement in SASS or SCSS for following HTML elements?

```
<div class="header" id="1">
<div class="header" id="2">
```

I found this Solution:
[Different Styles for same class name but different id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150244/different-styles-for-same-class-name-but-different-id)

But this seems the traditional solution, what I image is syntax like this:

```
.header{
    [if #1]{

   }
   [else if #2]{

   }
}
```

If there do not exist such syntax, I wonder what is the concern of such implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: How is your approach better than the 'traditional' (sigh...) approach? It certainly seems more verbose, and redundant.

Comment: Humm.. I think it can be more clear to see the relation? I'm not very sure about the benefits and flaws.

Comment: The question you link to is different since the IDs and classes are on different elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors themselves are made up of conditional statements. Since the ID and class are on the same element, concatenate the selectors using `&` as per normal:

```
.header{
   &#\1 {
   }

   &#\2 {
   }
}
```

Even though it might seem strange to append an ID selector to a class selector, it's perfectly valid. ID selectors don't have to be at the beginning of a compound selector like type or universal selectors do. But if it still rubs you the wrong way, there is nothing wrong with just using the ID selectors alone without qualifying them with the class selector (unless those same IDs are used differently elsewhere, in which case you should really rethink your HTML structure).

Note also that you need to escape the digits with a backslash in order for the ID selectors to be recognized, as CSS identifiers cannot normally start with a digit.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock! The digit id is just for illustrating problem. Thanks for you remind.